# Disable noisy timer on a magic chef gas range model 6458xst

Tags: gas, stove, timer

Does  anyone knows how to access the timer and disable it on  a **Magic Chef gas range model 6458xst**.  I would be more than interested to find out!

It is a flat stove and the timer is right in front of the burners. The top of stove will one not totally come off even though I've removed all visible screws.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Does anyone knows how to access the timer` ... yes ... a repair technician knows ... call one

Comment: No they don’t they don’t touch that age stove!

Comment: Would it make noise when the timer is not in use? You need to get to your user's manual to find out where the control module is located. If you are lucky, it might tell you how to disassemble the lid/cover that covers the circus.

Comment: Fixed it,There is no user manual as near as I can figure and on that addresses that particular issue.

Comment: Don't use the noisy, built in timer. Use an egg timer, digital timer, clock on your phone, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it myself by removing all the screws holding the front plate on taking out the wires and clipping the one going to the timer.